# Custom component props type working fine in the same file but behaving abnormaly when imported

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript, react-tsx

I have a custom component named `StyledView`. Its props are bit complex and based on conditional types
Here's the complete prop defination:

```
type StyledViewCommonPropsI = {
  bg?: boolean;
};

type StyledViewPressableProps<T> = AnimatedProps<PressableProps> & {
    disableRipple?: T;
  };

type StyledViewOpacityProps<T> = AnimatedProps<TouchableOpacityProps> & {
    disableRipple: T;
  };

type StyledViewTouchableProps<T, K = boolean | undefined> = (K extends true
  ? StyledViewOpacityProps<K>
  : StyledViewPressableProps<K>) & {
  touchable: T;
};

type StyledViewNonTouchableProps<T> = AnimatedProps<ViewProps> & {
    touchable?: T;
  };

type StyledViewProps<T = boolean> = (T extends true
  ? StyledViewTouchableProps<T>
  : StyledViewNonTouchableProps<T>) & StyledViewCommonPropsI;
```

Now if I use the `StyledView` component in the same file as it is defined, it is working fine there. But if I import the component in another file and use it, the props behave abnormaly.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["app/common/*"],
      "@kaksha/*": ["app/kaksha/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

`<StyledView onPress={()=>{}}/>` this should throw an error because `onPress` is not available on `StyledViewNonTouchableProps` which should the type because `touchable` prop is undefined.

In the same file it throws error, but as soon as I import it in another file and use it, the error disappears.